# Windows Store template is not available in Visual Studio 2012 Express for Desktop

Tags: c#, templates, visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps

I use VS 2012 Express for Desktop. I want to create the Windows Store Blank App (XAML).

However this template is not available inside VS. I tried to search one online. My try was unsuccessful.

Here on SoF I've read several topics that answer the similar question. And people say that this kind of template is (should be) available in VS 2012. I have Windows 8 with all last updates.

How can I add the Windows Store Template to my VS 2012?

Thank you

Comment: That's by design, "for Desktop" is the hint.  You'll want the "for Windows" version of Express instead.  Or get the retail edition, all-in-one.

Comment: So I need to use Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows 8? If so, can I install 2 instanses of VS 2012 for Desktop and for Windows 8 simultanously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you need Visual Studio Express for Windows to build store apps, not VSE for Desktop. You can find it [here](http://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#d-express-windows-8).

Comment: The link directs me to VS 2013. However, I can't use VS 2013 on Windows 8 to create apps for Windows Store. If I use VS 2013 I need to install Windows 8.1 only.

Comment: @plywoods: Why not update to 8.1?

Comment: @plywoods: true, sorry. There should be one for 2012 too, I think it's this one: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30664